# C++ Argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char"

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, c-strings, palindrome

My instructor asked me to make a program using cstring that checks if program is palindrome.
why its giving me "Argument  of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char" error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "";
    int strcmpVal;
    int length = str.length();
    cout << "******************************" << endl;
    cout << "PALINDROME" << endl;
    cout << "******************************" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    char* cStr = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cStr, str.c_str());
    for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++)
    {
        strcmpVal = strcmp(cStr[i],cStr[(length -1) -1]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error message, in particular which line it is referring to?

Comment: "_"Argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char" error._" When asking about error messages, always copy-paste them, instead of trying to paraphrase them. There is no way, that the error is about trying to convert to `const char`, instead of `const char*`. `char` is not the same as pointer-to-`char`: `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this statement

```
int length = str.length();
```

does not make sense because the object `str` is yet empty. You have to calculate the length after a string will be entered.

The standard C function `strcmp` compares strings not single characters. That is the type of the expression `cStr[i]` is `char` while the function awiats an argument of the type `char *` that would have the expression `cStr` if is passed to the function.

So use instead this loop

```
size_t i = 0;
size_t length = str.length();
while ( i < length / 2 && cStr[i] == cStr[length - i - 1] ) i++;

if ( i == length / 2 ) std::cout << "The string is a palindrome.\n";
```

Take into account that these statements

```
char* cStr = new char[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(cStr, str.c_str());
```

are redundant.

You could just write

```
const char *cStr = str.c_str();
```

Otherwise you need to free allocated memory after it is not used any more.

```
delete [] cStr;
```

Comment: but for some reason visual studio does not allow me to use strcmp on strings.

Comment: @Albert And do not use. What is the problem? I showed you how the loop can be written.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcmp(cStr[i], cStr[(length - 1) - 1]);
```

`cStr[i]` is a `char`, but the arguments of `strcmp` must be `char*`s (pointer to `char`).

But using `strcmp` is wrong here anyway, you just want to compare `char`, therefore you need rather:

```
strcmpVal = cStr[i] == cStr[(length -1) -1]);
```

But there are more issues. I let this as an exercise.

Comment: but for some reason visual studio does not allow me to use strcmp on strings.

Comment: @Albert that's exactly the point, `cStr[i]` is a `char`. Anyway as you write in C++ you should stick to `std::string`.